# How to set CMake variable to include directory

Tags: cmake, include, command-line-arguments

When trying to build [this library](https://github.com/sweeneychris/RpolyPlusPlus) with Cmake from the Developer Command Prompt for VS, I get this error

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindEigen.cmake:77 (MESSAGE):
  Failed to find Eigen - Could not find eigen3 include directory, set
  EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR to path to eigen3 include directory, e.g.
  /usr/local/include/eigen3.
```

I'd like find out what was intended of me here: am I to set `EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR` with a command line argument or by editing the make file?

I've tried `cmake -D EIGEN_INGLUDE_DIR=C:\Users\a\Downloads\eigen-3.3.7\eigen-3.3.7 .` but received the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that value you have assigned to `EIGEN_INGLUDE_DIR` is actually an **include directory** of the Eigen? E.g., do you **actually** have a file `C:\Users\a\Downloads\eigen-3.3.7\eigen-3.3.7\Eigen\Core`?

Comment: Yes I do have that file. So that should work? thanks I'll investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmake -D EIGEN_INGLUDE_DIR=C:\Users\a\Downloads\eigen-3.3.7\eigen-3.3.7 .` failed without creating any files (`cmake ..` at least started building) and gave me this error

> CMake Error: The source "C:/Users/a/Downloads/RpolyPlusPlus-master/RpolyPlusPlus-master/build/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "C:/Users/a/Downloads/RpolyPlusPlus-master/RpolyPlusPlus-master/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.

So I just ended up adding this to the .cmake file:

```
# TODO: Add standard Windows search locations for Eigen.
LIST(APPEND EIGEN_CHECK_INCLUDE_DIRS
  /usr/local/include
  /usr/local/homebrew/include # Mac OS X
  /opt/local/var/macports/software # Mac OS X.
  /opt/local/include
  /usr/include
  C:\\Users\\a\\Downloads\\eigen-3.3.7)  <---------------------------------------
```